# Angular directive without timeout service does not work

Tags: angularjs

In angularJS, I have written a directive to display data. This data is fetched by a http service from remote database.

If I apply below *timeout* service in code, then result is displayed on the html page as http service returns in one second.

```
$timeout(function () {
         $scope.treeRoot = $scope.$eval('serviceResult') || {};
 }, 1000);
```

If i do not use timeout service, then page does not show any data because $scope.treeRoot is empty e.g.

```
$scope.treeRoot = $scope.$eval('serviceResult') || {};
```

In production, the http service can take time more than one second to return, is there any generic solution.

Comment: Can you show the HTML and the link function of the directive?

Comment: this seems like an odd place to use `$scope.$eval`.  if you show the *entire* function, not just the `$timeout`, as a [mcve], it might make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Angular's [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service which allows to return a promise.

After the promise, e.g. $http request, is resolved, you can populate `$scope.treeRoot` with the results.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

AS suggested in one answer you have to use the $http promises and capture the result in response.

Here is an example with some code.

Service:

```
app.factory('myService', ['$http',
    function($http){
        var obj = {};

        obj.get = function (q) {
            return $http.get('/your_get_url')
        };
        obj.post = function (q, object) {
            return $http.post('/your_post_url', object)
        };

        return obj;
    }
]);
```

In your controller,

```
allControllers.controller('changePasswordController', ['$scope','myService',
    function($scope,myService) {

        myService.get().then(function (result) {
                $scope.treeRoot = 'use your result here'
            },function error(result)
            {
                console.log(result)
            })      

    }
])
```

This replaces your timeout issue.